# Anything like AngularJS's $http.pendingRequests in Angular's HttpClient

Tags: angularjs, angular, httpclient

I was working on **AngularJS** before and I know there is a build-in property called **$http.pendingRequests** which can tell me if there is any pending http request existing.

Now I am working on **Angular 4.4.6** and using **HttpClient** from **@angular/common/http**.

**My Goal**

I would like to use such result to display a loading message when any http request happens and hide it when all requests finish.

**My Search**

Did NOT get any luck via **search** or going through all the @angular/common/http **source codes**.

**My Question**

- How can I find if there is any pending http request existing.
- Or I have to implement it by myself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can just use an interceptor that increments a count when a request is being sent, and decrements it when a response is received: https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses

Comment: Hi JB Nizet, it's just what I was thinking. I wanted to confirm if I have to do like this by myself. :-)